# Core Data migration issues in iOS 11.3 works fine in earlier devices

Tags: sqlite, core-data, core-data-migration, xcode9.3

I am working on core data from last one years. In my app, there are thousands of records of for initial listing. So I used local SQLite file in bundle and place in document directory when an app launches first time in the device. My application is live in appstore. Form iOS 11.3 which are launched before one week my app works fine in earlier os version. But in ios 11.3 application gives me "NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores".

When "addPersistentStore(ofType:configurationName:at:options:)" line executed it gives me hashes log of the entity in it four entity hashes are different but don't understand issues. it works in iOS 11.2 fine, but issues come in iOS 11.3 devices.

[image]

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem with a coredata lightweight migration. I just added a new coredata model and some attributtes. And it crash when the app arrive with my final users with ios 11.3.0 (15E216) :(

Comment: I have a similar problem with an app thats been working fine since ios 8.4 worked fine up until 11.2 - anyone made any progress on this yet ?